# How to Pass DATA from HTML to Servlet?

Tags: html, servlets

[My layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtLIQ.png)

I have 4 pages where I need to collect the multiple fields and store in my Database. How do I fetch all the data from each page **(Clients/Transactions/GeneralSetup and Environment)** and send it to the "FetchEnvironmentData" class?

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h6>Deploy Apps:</h6>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Profile7</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebCSR</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebAdmin</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebClient</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
           <h6>From System Date:</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='initialDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h6>To System Date:</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='finalDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h5>DAYENDS to run: 7</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h6>Users:</h6>
            <div class="well">
        

        <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Profile7</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebCSR</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebAdmin</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">WebClient</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <!--Pagination-->
    <div class="text-center">
        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination text-center">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="GeneralSetup.jsp">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="Clients.jsp">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="Accounts.jsp">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="Transactions.jsp">4</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="Clients.jsp">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to test only with the name so far **without success**

```
public class FetchEnvironmentData extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Any helP? THank you

Comment: If you want to get all your form values in servlet, then use **name** attribute with each element in the form.

Comment: Having multiple pages isnt a problem?

Comment: There's no submit button in the first page. Only in the last

Comment: If you have multiple pages, then either you have to submit each form individually to servlet or you can store your form values in **session** and then on final submission store all those values in DB.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Form

```
<form action="your_page" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Servlet Code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     

        String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");           
        out.println(fname);

}
```

system.out shows console out put

Comment: what do u mean by my page? the class where's the doPost? or the html? My page is http://localhost:8080/Project_ATP_war_exploded/GeneralSetup.jsp

Comment: your page means your servelt.java page

Comment: How do I get the src/com.myproject.jsp/FetchEnvironmentData ? I try to ../src and doesnt exist https://gyazo.com/48f8096bd00d0a016c3a9a9b1628b6c7

Comment: only FetchEnvironmentData